# Debugging MvvmCross application in Xamarin Studio with MvvmCross sources

Tags: mvvmcross, xamarin-studio

I'd like to be able to step through the MvvmCross sources in the debugging of a MvvmCross application.
And I want to keep the process of keeping the MvvmCross library up-to-date simple. Currently the MvvmCross project files cannot even be openened in Xamarin Studio without editing lots of .csproj files (due to some PCL/project platform issues).

I've found that using the MvvmCross-Binaries assemblies (and their .pdb and .mdb files)  and putting their source code into "C:\Projects\Misc\MVVMCROSS" does the trick. You can even step through the sources and set break points.

That is not the most self-contained solution.

I am wondering, if there is a better way.

Comment: What branch of MvvmCross are you building and what version of the XS tools are you using. The v3.1 branch of MvvmCross should build in XS using the VS2013 PCL assemblies that Microsoft licensed for cross platform code in November 2013.

Comment: @Stuart: On branch v3. I saw v3.1 as an option. But then I'd be interested to know what a good setup is. I'd prefer to keep only the binaries in my own repo. I toyed with git subtree, but the size of your repo is substantial in comparison to the binaries. Maybe there is a trick with hard links, etc. Just thought I'd ask.

Answer (score 2):

MvvmCross now contains the symbol packages so you can debug it: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/pull/889